# Saving a full screenshot of just one display on a multiheaded system on macOS?

Tags: screenshot, macos

I have a workstation with 5 monitors, but I need to save just one entire screen / display contents immediately to a file (a region is an option, but it would need to be a predefined region at the click of a key combo).  The existing built-in screenshot functionality of the OS doesn't do this.

Is there an app that facilitates this on macOS?

Answer (score 1):

The program I found that solves this issue at least in part is [Monosnap](https://monosnap.com/welcome). It has a function under Preferences -> Hotkeys called "Capture previous area", which, when used, takes the same snapshot of the first defined region as was captured via "Capture area":

[image: monosnap example]

All of these images are then saved to Monosnap under the Pictures folder if you have that option checked in the "Advanced" tab.

Answer (score 0):

[GreenShot](http://getgreenshot.org/) is now [available for MacOS](http://getgreenshot.org/2017/01/10/mac-os-launch/); I use it on Windows, and it does just about everything I need. By default, you get the following choices:

[image]

"Capture full screen" by default captures the single monitor that the mouse pointer is on; there's an INI hack for it that will make it capture the entire multi-head extended desktop instead (or you can use the region capture instead).

"Capture window" captures the currently-active window, regardless of which screen it's on, or even if it goes across the junction between screens.

"Capture Region" lets you select an arbitrary rectangular region from your (possibly multi-headed) desktop.

"Capture Last Region" lets you capture the most recently defined region from a "Capture Region".

Comment: Great to see another option that has this same function, thanks for sharing that. One thing I noticed on the macOS version is that it's not free like the Windows version; apparently they put forth a lot of effort creating it and are charging ~$2 right now (and it may go up from what they're saying). The thing I haven't been able to see yet is whether or not the Mac version has that same "Capture last region" option as per the Windows version.

Comment: @ylluminate - OK, I missed that it wasn't free; I didn't dig beyond the page with the announcement, because I don't use Mac.

Comment: Np there, still glad to see another potential solution. I don't know if I feel like plunking down $2 yet to just find out if the "Capture last region" is also there as per the Windows version or not since they say it doesn't share feature parity... :)

Comment: Assuming that the features that do exist work the same, your need would be satisfied by the "capture screen", provided that you can be sure that the mouse pointer is on the screen that you want captured at the time of the capture. Region capture is sort of a last-ditch for single screen.

Comment: My problem is that I have to perform hundreds of captures of the same region since I have multiple monitors and NOTHING seems to capture a single display / screen (they all seem to want to grab all monitors). So, for example, "Capture previous area" works out well in Monosnap for macOS and "Capture last region" would presumably work well in GreatShot, if it's there.

Comment: Again, with Greenshot, the "capture screen" seems to capture ONLY THE DISPLAY WITH THE MOUSE POINTER at the time of invocation - at least, that's its behavior on Windows. No need for diddling the region; just keep the mouse pointer on the correct screen and hit Ctrl-PrtSc (or whatever is configured).

Answer (score 0):

I use Layers for this - not only a ton of controls, but also captures Mac OS UI elements all as separate layers in a PSD, which is very helpful for documenting UI.

Comment: Is that still around? Thought it died years ago. The domain now throws up a page about steroids...

Comment: Yup. The developer folded, but it still works well on Mac OS 10.12.6.

Comment: Are you finding any links for current download or can you up an archive?

Comment: Looks like the original developer (Spanish group) has folded - none of their various web properties are up anymore. I'll see about putting up a dropbox link.

Comment: That would be nice to have around. Reminds me of Skitch 1, that I keep and use regularly (and of which have put up a download archive). It's looking like we'll have to stick with macOS 10.13 to use some of these older apps going forward since 10.14 is going to screw us all on the 32-bit front, etc.